# Set different view for specific product in google analytics

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-filters

I have three types of product on my e-commerce site. I want to create a different view where I can see the transition, conversion, funnel, goal etc only of a specific product. The URL of the details page of products are

```
example.com/book/<dynamic_id>
example.com/electronics/<dynamic_id>
example.com/fashion/<dynamic_id>
```

But the other pages like cart, shipping, payment pages URL are same, like :

```
exmaple.com/cart
exmaple.com/shipping
exmaple.com/payment
```

I've added a filter using Request URI, but the problem is it only tracking the details page, not conversion or any other metrics.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to modify your filter (I am guessing that's Include type filter?) to include both values. Note the filter pattern supports regex so something like this should work

- (/book/)|(/cart)|(/shipping)|(/payment)
- (/electronics/)|(/cart)|(/shipping)|(/payment)
- (/fashion/)|(/cart)|(/shipping)|(/payment)

Please note, that if you use two Include filters, GA would apply both one after another effectively taking your data to match both of them which is in most cases not what people want

[image]